# Can we Make Approval Process Optional for Sometime?

Tags: approval-process

We have an approval process on one of Opportunity's child object. Approval Process is almost 6 steps approval process.

We have recently migrated to PROD and for Data Update we don't need to follow Approval process.We just need to auto update those records to approved in order to bypass validation rule.

Our client wants approval process optional till next 2 months until environment is ready completely for Business User.

We can not remove the approval process as we need it after sometime. for now we just need to auto approve it.

Is there a way to make it Optional for sometime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a WF Rule temporary that sets the Record Status to Approved.Create a WF Rule when you create a new record.

For Existing Records,Find out those records Via Data Loader or Workbench and Set the Status to Approved via Data loader.

When your environment is ready then you can disable those WF Rule.

Another option would be create a checkbox field and Bypass it in your validation.

Let me know if it helps.